# Refresh directory Size in Linux

Tags: linux, aix

I have delete all files older than two days from my directories using:

```
find . -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
```

the files got deleted fine but the size of the directories has not changed is there anything I can do to refresh the size? I have tries `pwd` but nothing.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked lsof?  If some application uses files they are not actually deleted till they close them.  But I am not sure that this affects dir size.